# Can't install pyenchant, how to solve this

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, pyenchant

I got a problem when tried to install pyenchant module.

[image]

I don't how to solve this problem. I google it, and did many ways but it still doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Paste code, not image. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think pyenchant does not work on 64 bits.
Can you use a python 32bits instead ?

Comment: My friends using 64 bits could install it easily, they got success for the first time.